# how to get the sitecollection url in ascx file

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, developer

I am trying to add a hyperlink for a document which is uploaded in the document library. I don't want to hardcode the url by giving the specific sever url like http://xyz:1112/documents/abc.doc. I want to have a retrieve the sitecollection url.

Answer (score 2):

In code-behind:

```
string fileUrl = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(SPContext.Current.Site.Url, "documents/foo.docx");
```

Or in .ascx file:

```
<a href='<%SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(SPContext.Current.Site.Url, "documents/foo.docx")%>'>click</a>
```

(would need the proper Import declaration)

or you can use client-side script with the variable `_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current url by using the `SPContext.Current` instance and working from there. For example:

```
// root site – eg. Web App url
string rootSiteCollectionURL = SPContext.Current.Web.Site.WebApplication.Sites[0].Url;

// site collection url
string SiteCollectionURL = SPContext.Current.Web.Site.Url;
```

Comment: I am trying to write it in ascx file for hyperlink <a href="http://xyz:1112/Documents/abc.tsv" target="_blank">. here i can't user spcontext right ??

Comment: In the code behind file , you can retrive url and then push it to <a tags href  /> . you can also use Javascript to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will create a hyperlink using the relative URL of the current SharePoint site, and whatever sub-item you’d like to link to

```
<a href=\”‘+_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl+’/Documents/abc.doc\” />
```